# Recreate grid mixins from lost sources

Tags: sass, grid-layout

In an old site the mixins to create the grid are lost. I'm not sure if it was using susy, or singularitygs .. but one of those two, I guess, adn older versions, I guess.

From the front end, I've been able to retrieve the rendered values. It seems the logic is simple ... but can anyone recreate the mixins to generate those ?

Here is some of the data I found. It uses a 36 column layout, but I'm not sure what the gutter size is .. and wether the columns include the gutters.

I'm looking for generic simple methods like push(), pull() and span(), *and* the numerics used in this setup

```
@mixin push1() {
  margin-left: 2.8125%; 
}
@mixin pull1() {
  margin-left: -2.8125%; 
}
@mixin span36() {
    width: 100%;
  float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

@mixin span34() {
    width: 94.375%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
@mixin span27() {
    width: 74.6875%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
@mixin span26() {
    width: 72%; // this i guessed
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
@mixin span25() {
    width: 69.0625%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
@mixin span24() {
    width: 66.25%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
@mixin span22() {
    width: 60.625%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
@mixin span18() {
    width: 49.375%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}

@mixin span17() {
    width: 46.5625%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
@mixin span15() {
    width: 40.9375%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
@mixin span12() {
    width: 32.5%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}

@mixin span11() {
    width: 29.6875%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}

@mixin span9() {
    width: 24.0625%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}

@mixin span6() {
    width: 15.625%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the span, apparently it has 36 columns and a 1.25 gutter; it divides the gutters evenly over the columns to span except for the last one, and divides the remainder over the columns. so

```
spanX = (100 - (36/x-1)*1.25)/(36/x)
```

take span17, thats

```
span17 = 100 - (36/17-1)*1.25) / (36/17) = 46.5625
```

i dont know why that even makes sense in a grid - you've got 1.11764705882 gutters there - but thats what the numbers say.

if you push or pull one column, you dont just push the column, but also the margin added to the column. so

```
pushX = 100/x+1.25/x
```